# How to make a page receiver using plugin mechanism in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress plugin, here is my `shortcode`, I want to use `[phx amount="20" color="green"]` in my post to render an anchor link, click which would direct to a page that can receive the `get` params and do some stuffs. I've made the `shortcode`, but how can I make such a page using plugin mechanism?

```
add_shortcode( 'phx', array( $this, 'phx_shortcode' ) );

function phx_shortcode( $attrs ) {
    $html = '';
    $customized_atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'amount' => '10',
        'color'  => 'green',
        ), $attrs, 'phx');

    $html .= "<a href='http://wordpress.dev?".
             "amount={$customized_atts['amount']}'>Pay</a>";

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would slot right into a custom plugin very easily. All you need to do is [put a header on top of the file](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/), place your custom plug-in into your site's `wp-content/plugins` folder and enable it when you login. The function will then be available to your WP site.

Here is a sample header with a subheader that I like to do to enhance code readability (NOTE: the subheader is not required but the main header is):

```
/*
Plugin Name:    My Custom Plugin
Plugin URI:     http://www.example.com/
Description:    What my plugin does
Version:        0.1.0
Author:         Phoenix
Author URI:     http://example.co
License:        CC Attribution-ShareAlike License
License URI:    https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
*/

/*
##################################
########### Shortcodes ###########
##################################

Explain in particular what this function does here.
*/

add_shortcode( 'phx', array( $this, 'phx_shortcode' ) );

function phx_shortcode( $attrs ) {
    $html = '';
    $customized_atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'amount' => '10',
        'color'  => 'green',
        ), $attrs, 'phx');

    $html .= "<a href='http://wordpress.dev?".
             "amount={$customized_atts['amount']}'>Pay</a>";

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but that's not what I mean. I want the anchor link to :http://wordpress.dev?amount=20 can be retrieved in my(this) plugin.

Comment: Change the 'amount' parameter to 20, no? Or do you want the amount parameter to be a variable set dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [`query_vars` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) to register the query variables with WordPress.

Once that is done you can retrieve them with [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

In your theme (`functions.php`) or a plugin:

```
function my_custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'amount';
    $vars[] .= 'color';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars_filter' );
```

In a template file or somewhere else:

```
$color = get_query_var('color');

$amount = get_query_var('amount');
```